# Which HTTP headers can be combined in a list?

Tags: http, http-headers

RFC 7230 says ([3.2.2 Field Order](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2), markup by me):

> A sender MUST NOT generate multiple header fields with the same field
> name in a message **unless either the entire field value for that
> header field is defined as a comma-separated list** [i.e., #(values)]
> or the header field is a well-known exception (as noted below).

Back in RFC2616, all the headers were contained in a single specification and one could browse through that spec for header definitions that have lists as values.

Nowadays, we have RFC7230 and friends, each specifying its own set of headers.

Is there an (authorative) list somewhere that holds the header names with list values? Or do I need to grep all related RFCs for `1#`?

Answer (score 1):

Of the [standard HTTP request headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Standard_request_fields), these can have multiple values separated by a comma `,`:

```
A-IM
Accept
Accept-Charset
Accept-Encoding
Accept-Language
Access-Control-Request-Headers
Cache-Control
Connection
Content-Encoding
Expect
Forwarded
If-Match
If-None-Match
Range
TE
Trailer
Transfer-Encoding
Upgrade
Via
Warning
```

these can have them separated by a semicolon `;`:

```
Content-Type
Cookie
Prefer
```

and these shouldn't have multiple values (or can but with some other syntax, for example the `User-Agent` header can pretty much be arbitrary text):

```
Accept-Datetime
Access-Control-Request-Method
Authorization
Content-Length
Content-MD5
Date
From
Host
HTTP2-Settings
If-Modified-Since
If-Range
If-Unmodified-Since
Max-Forwards
Origin
Pragma
Proxy-Authorization
Referer
User-Agent
```

This doesn't include response headers, and any non-standard HTTP request headers. I made these lists by quickly glancing at the RFC listed in [that table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Standard_request_fields) for each header, I could've misclassified a few.

Comment: This code is "in production" here: https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/blob/68ad222e2945b94e6f9f533764c7ea025a3e4360/src/util.ts#L2329

Answer (score 0):

The only known exception is `Set-Cookie`. Many HTTP frameworks that encapsulate HTTP headers tend to treat all headers the exact same way, but have a specific exception for `Set-Cookie`. No other headers have this problem, and no standard new headers would be introduced with this problem.

Pick a random HTTP framework for any language, and chances are that there there's some special handling for *just* `Set-Cookie`.

It's possible that other non-standard headers have this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Your answer describes the second part of the `unless` statement: _"... or the header field is a well-known exception (as noted below)"_. I'm interested in the first part. If I am correct, you could for example have multiple `accept` headers that are then combined into a comma separated list...

Comment: @eckes idk if this answers this, but yes you CAN receive multiple Accept headers and they would be semantically equivalent to getting 1 comma-separated Accept header.

Comment: But not every comma-separated HTTP header may be split into many. To be on the safe side, when generating HTTP headers it's better to just always combine multiple headers with the same name into 1, except `Set-Cookie`.

Comment: `But not every comma-separated HTTP header may be split into many` Which one not? Do you have a reference for this? And I'm not on the generating side but consume the headers on the server side (own server).

Comment: @eckes. Right, I understand. I don't think there is a definite list. I think most parsing-side implementations take the assumption that they will simply not get incorrectly split headers. They assume that if they are split, it must have been allowed. Most frameworks do this, but it's not a great answer.

Comment: @eckes not sure if this helps, but here's the official list of standard headers: https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml